# Can I use Visual Studio 2015 and the Windows 7 SDK?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

New to windows development, so might be a silly question, but can I use Visual Studio Community 2015 to develop Visual C++ apps for windows 7 and upwards with the Windows 7 SDK?

I'm running Windows 7 and have the 7.1 SDK installed, as well as Visual Studio Community 2015 (as well as two Windows 10 SDK's that were installed automatically as part of visual studio).

Visual studio lets me build windows 10 apps, which I don't want. But there's no option to create windows 7 applications. How can I make VS find the windows 7 SDK?

We really need Visual C++ for this project, so C# etc. seems out of the question.

Thanks

Comment: Trying to create a Win10 UWP app with SDK v7 makes no sense.  Creating one on a machine that boots Win7 doesn't make much sense either, too hard to test it.  Be sure to use the appropriate project template to get started.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify, I'm not interested in windows 10, it's just that visual studio 2015 automatically installs the windows 10 SDK and doesn't recognise the windows 7 SDK or provide templates for it! Have edited the question now to make this clear.

Comment: The v10 SDK is fine to create apps that run on Win7.  Just define `_WIN32_WINNT` to 0x601 so you can't accidentally use any declarations that cannot work on Win7.  If that doesn't help then you'll need to explain what *exactly* goes wrong.  Post a snippet, post an error message, anything to clarify your issue.

Comment: I don't even have code yet! I can use the visual studio templates to create a blank visual c++ app, but then the compile and run options think I want to create a windows 10 application.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what you mean by "windows 10 application". Try to be precise about it.

Comment: Ok. I go to Windows / Visual C++ and create a "Blank App (Universal Windows)". I click OK and then I get to choose a target and minimum windows version, both of which are windows 10. If I OK that, I get a bare app at least but it obviously won't run on my windows 7 machine (i.e. next to the green run button I can select "Device" or "Remote Machine" to test my blank application)

Comment: Why are you creating a UWP app? That can't run on Windows 7. You need to create the right type of project. That's your real problem.

Comment: Great! So what is the correct type of app? Post it as an answer if you like :-)

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. Console app. Win32 GUI. MFC. Lots of choices. What you have available also depends on how you installed VS, which I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, trying to create a GUI app (WinForms I suppose). Had assumed this would be a pretty default option, but will do some more digging...

Comment: WinForms is a .net framework. You want to write a C++/CLI program?

Comment: What I _think_ I want is a Win32 or an MFC app.
Judging by https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875053.aspx , it seems there's no "Designer" features for this?

Comment: Is there anything you know you want to do in the first place? And what does your New Project window look like?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the VS 2010 compiler toolset if it is installed, from Visual Studio 2015. This [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/24/stuck-on-an-older-toolset-version-move-to-visual-studio-2015-without-upgrading-your-toolset/) seems to explain it well. The trick is to load the old project and then do not upgrade/retarget it in the new IDE.

Comment: May as well use the VS2015 compiler which is perfectly capably of producing output that works on Windows 7 and indeed earlier. Why make life difficult?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The new compiler does introduce source incompatibilities (newer C++ standard support etc.) which may be unwanted. If it's not about the toolset specifically, of course you're right.

Comment: Judging by the comments, asker doesn't really understand the issues. So your advice here is likely to send him down the wrong path. What asker needs is help in understanding the issues.

Comment: The asker seems to be confused by the myriad types of projects VS can create out of the box in the first place, not about using the compilers after making a project.